# how to format the count if it is too large in value in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

This is my buildCountText function in flutter, where i am passing label and count as my arguments, I am using this function to show my count of followers in an app, but I don't know how to format my count if it's value is large in thousands or millions,I don't want to write the whole figure if its in million , I just want to write it as 1M(for example). but I don't know how to format it in that way.

```
buildCountText(String label, int count) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 6),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          //text: label,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "OpenSans", color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
                text: label,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: "OpenSans", fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
            TextSpan(
                text:_isLoading?" ...": ' $count', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use number formatter.  https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html

```
var f = NumberFormat.compact();
print(f.format(100000)); //<= prints 100K
```